# git merge, can I substitute some files in one branch with files in another one?

Tags: git, git-merge

So, this is the situation.
I have a repo with let's say a lot of files. I have only touched let's say about 15 files... there are a lot of files, that I don't need to touch/modify and they are out of my scope of work, but for logic reasons they are in the same repo.

I had the following situation:

```
Branch A     Branch B

Commit A.1

Commit A.2   Commit B.2

Commit A.3   Commit B.3

             Commit B.4
             .........
             Commit B.N
```

Branch A is the origin (master), Branch B is remote and local, where I kept working, I need the files in branch B, at the state of the last commit B.N to be in branch A (origin / master), so basically I don't want to merge my changes in A, I want to override those files, is there a way to do this quickly?
As a solution I thought in copy and paste the files, and override them in a new commit, but that will mess the history of those files, any options with git?

Comment: It is not clear if your local changes are in branch A or B, I understand you want to override the state of branch B by the state of the remote, but not in branch A ?

Comment: everything has been pushed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a fake merge, that you modify before committing.
I would do so in a separate clone, in order to not disturb your existing working tree which is currently set to branch B, where you are working

```bash
git switch A
git merge --ours B
# copy files from B to A
git commit -m "Import B.x commit to A"
git push
```

The `git merge --ours B` records a merge from B to A, but does not modify anything on A: that gives you the opportunity to copy only the files you want.